# how to import eclipse libraries into intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have to use some eclipse libraries (org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3. *), But I would like to continue developing in intellij, is there any way to insert them? thank you

Comment: You may download JARs for those libraries and add them in "Project Structure | Libraries"

Comment: @y.bedrov. thank you